# Derangements and Lagrange Remainder

Tags: co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

At some point the following question came up:

Is the number of derangements $D(n)$ the closest integer to $\frac{n!}e?$

Since $$D(n) = n! \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(-1)^i}{i!},$$ the answer is **YES** by using the Lagrange form of the remainder in Taylor's theorem:
$$\left|e^{-1} - \frac{D(n)}{n!}\right| = \frac{\exp{c_n}}{(n+1)!},$$ for some $c_n \in (-1, 0).$

Never content to leave well enough alone, we ask: how does $c_n$ depend on $n?$
Here are the experimental results, computed with *Mathematica* to $1000$ decimal places: the graph is of $1/c_n:$

[image: Lagrange constant]

It seems that, to high precision, $c_n \sim -1/n.$ Is this known? How would you prove such a thing?

Comment: Linear approximation of the exponential near zero?  After all, exp c_n is pretty close to 1.  Gerhard "That's What Your Graph Says" Paseman, 2017.12.11.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman You puzzle me strangely...

Comment: Maybe I made an error. The quantity represented by exp c_n looks near 1 -  1/n to me. I am unsure about what prompts your question. It looks like an undergraduate exercise to me, but then I haven't put pencil to paper for this one yet . Gerhard "Others' Puzzlement Is Personally Puzzling" Paseman, 2017.12.11

Comment: @GerhardPaseman What prompted my question: curiosity. Undergraduate exercise: knock yourself out - it is not at all obvious (to my primitive high-school mind) that $c_n$ should even go to $0\dots$

Comment: See also **2.2 Examples and Special Cases** in *Enumerative Combinatorics* (p. 227).

Comment: @Igor: You forgot to say what "derangement" means. Fortunately it is in the Wikipedia where the formula is proved.

Comment: @MarkSapir Sorry, I assumed it was standard (comes from teaching combinatorics courses :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly,

$$\eqalign{\exp(c_n) &=(n+1)! \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{i-n-1}}{i!}\cr
&= 1 - \frac{1}{n+2} + O(1/n^2)} $$
so indeed
$$ c_n = \log \left(1 - \frac{1}{n+2} + O(1/n^2)\right) = -\frac{1}{n} + O(1/n^2)$$

Comment: Oh Robert, you make everything look like high school! Gerhard "Was Going For College-Level Answer" Paseman, 2017.12.11.

Comment: Truly you are wise in the ways of science :)